# Angular automated testing using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation

I'm looking for some advice. I'm currently trying to create end-to-end test using selenium (Java) for an angular application. I don't think I need to mention how much of a pain this process has been because of the dynamic elements on the page.

I have looked at using NgWebDriver. But I have a problem with this approach. All of my elements on the page look like this:

```
<button _ngcontent-tmh-c54="" id="addNewPartnerSystem" pbutton="" label="Add New Partner System" type="button" class="p-element ui-button p-button p-component ng-star-inserted"><span class="p-button-label">Add New Partner System</span></button>
```

I have tried using the id's provided by the developers, in this case "addNewPartnerSystem", but selenium shows no element found error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your page is rendered dynamically and assuming your XPath for the selection is correct, you need to wait until the page is loaded.
Thread.sleep(milliseconds) will do the trick.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, I have tried thread.sleep, I have also done explicit and implicit waits using selenium. None of which seem to work

Comment: Can I see how are you trying to find the element? The code snippet with XPath would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Thanks for getting back to me. The Xpath is '//*[@id="addNewPartnerSystem"]'

Answer (score 0):

You have try the below solutions

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("Xpath")));
elem.click();
```

***OR***

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Let me know if this does not work for you

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the suggestions. Unfortunately both of the options don't work. I had already tried the wait.until method when writing the question, but no thought of using JS executor. I've tried JS executor and still getting the following error: 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#addNewPartnerSystem"}'

Comment: have you tried other locators like //*[contains(text(),'Add New Partner System')] 

or....

//*[normalize-space(text())='Add New Partner System']

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried both of the locators that your provided. Even with webdriverwait's and still no luck. Thank you for trying

Comment: can you provide the url for this

Comment: You won't be able to access the site. It's an internal cooperate intranet site

Comment: Check the HTML source than there might be shadow root or Iframe exist

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though all I had to do was switch between iFrames. Thanks for the comments and suggestions